# How to compare 2 two-dimensional lists in python according to a given condition?

Tags: python

This function compares 2 matrices element by element, compares according to the principle that the corresponding elements should have the same parity

```py
def equals(matr1, matr2):
    if len(matr1) != len(matr2):
        return False
    for index1 in range(len(matr1)):
        if len(matr1[index1]) != len(matr2[index1]):
            return False
        for index2 in range(len(matr1[index1])):
            if matr1[index1][index2] % 2 != matr2[index1][index2] % 2:
                return False
    return True
```

```
matrix [[1, 2], [3, 4]] # - satisfies the condition
matrix [[4, 6], [4, 5]] # - does not satisfy the condition
```

how to write this function in one line?

Comment: On which condition we can say that the lists satisfy the condition or not.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, this is my first question, I'll fix it now

Comment: ah they used three quotes ' instead of back-quotes ` - such a change is already suggested and can be made and improved via the [edit] button!

Comment: What do you mean `matrix1` satisfies the condition and `matrix2` doesn't? You are asking to compare _two_ matrices and return a single `True` or `False` for the pair, aren't you?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One arguably dirty way to go would be to "map" the matrices to their remainders mod 2 using list comprehensions, then comparing the matrices:

```py
equals = lambda mat1, mat2: [[e1 % 2 for e1 in l1] for l1 in mat1] == [[e2 % 2 for e2 in l2] for l2 in mat2]
```

you could deduplicate this using a function, cleaning it up a bit:

```py
def matrix_mod(mat, mod):
    return [[e1 % mod for e1 in l1] for l1 in mat]
def equals(mat1, mat2):
    return matrix_mod(mat1, 2) == matrix_mod(mat2, 2)
```

Comment: @SharimIqbal because they have the same remainder when all scalars are divided by two.

Comment: thank you, it works correctly, but why is this method dirty?

Comment: @Alex because your function is much more readable, and there's repeated code

Comment: I consider the above slightly dirty because it duplicates the matrix mapping code. Other than that it may also be considered somewhat inefficient because it creates a copy of the matrix with the remainders (but I think that isn't a concern in Python).

Comment: @PranavHosangadi is also right.

Comment: @Alex FWIW, the second version is clean enough if you don't care about performance. Your current version is fine as well though. Shorter isn't always better.